# Array Get Elements Backwards

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function that returns an array with all the elements up until, but not including, the element at the given index.

```
function getElementsUpTo(array, n) {
      var output = [];
      for (var i=n; i < array.length; i++){
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
      return output;
    }

    var output = getElementsUpTo(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3) 
    console.log(output); // --> must be['a', 'b', 'c'] but its displaying [c, d, e]
```

As you can see it must return ['a', 'b', 'c'] but its displaying [c, d, e].
Any idea?

Comment: Because `var i=n; i < array.length; i++` is pretty clearly explicitly *starting* at `n` and running until the end…!?

Comment: FWIW: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: The title of this question is very uninformative

Comment: [*slice*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.slice) is a much better option because it will not create elements where there are none. The *for* loop solution will create elements for missing members with a value of *undefined*, e.g. in `[0,,,,4]`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't use slice in javascript?It's very handy.

Your starting index is 'n' i.e very clear that you have gone wrong here.
Using your logic

```
function getElementsUpTo(array, n) {
      var output = [];
      for (var i=0; i < n; i++){
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
      return output;
    }

    var output = getElementsUpTo(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3) 
    console.log(output);
```

Using the slice method,it's even more simpler to do

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e']
var output = arr.slice(0,3)
```

Same output but only 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

You started at position that you need to stop at, instead of starting from the beginning of the array. Also, you need to stop at the index before n

```
function getElementsUpTo(array, n) {
      var output = [];
      for (var i=0; i < n; i++){ //need to start at index 0, and stop at index n-1
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
      return output;
    }

    var output = getElementsUpTo(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3) 
    console.log(output); // --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

The main culprit is this line:

```
for (var i=n; i < array.length; i++){ // ... rest of code
```

It seems that your function returns the first nth element. So the index has to start from the first, which is 0. The loop condition should be `i < n` so that the loop would stop at the nth loop. This means that the last loop would be the (n - 1)th loop, which is fine since we start at 0 anyway. So the final code should be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
```

Comment: *"The main culprit is this line"* - The main culprit? Or the only culprit?

Answer (score 1):

You're using n as the start point for your reading.
what you'd want is something looking like:

```
function getElementsUpTo(array, n) {
      var output = [];
      for (var i=0; i < n; i++){
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
      return output;
    }
```

for future reference:

1) array items start at array[0] and go up to array[length-1]

2) the 'i' you put in there gets the item in that spot in the array.

ie: array[0] => 'a' in your case.

So by starting with i=n you were telling the array to start at position n, and i>array.length tells it to keep going until the end. (remembering that array[array.length] will throw an out of bounds error, because arrays start at 0, not at 1.)